# Функция mail в php

Tags: php, email

**От кого** придет сообщение, отправленное с помощью функции `mail()`? Нигде не могу найти об этом информацию.

В некоторых случаях отправителя дописывают в `additional_headers`, но ведь так можно и что угодно дописать, хоть `barackobama@whitehouse.gov`

Comment: от хоста, hostname которblй

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если вы имеете ввиду отправителя письма, то оно будет таким, каким вы его укажите явно. Функция [mail](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) всего лишь передает вашему мейл серверу (скорее всего [postfix](http://www.postfix.org)) все данные, переданные вами в функцию.

Это всего лишь инструмент, который делает запрос на почтовый сервер адресата, а что вы там укажите это на вашей совести. Самое плохое, что может случится это черные списки и спам листы. Не забудьте так же про [DKIM](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/DomainKeys_Identified_Mail) и [SPF](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sender_Policy_Framework)

Answer (score 2):

Все зависит от настроек вашего сервера. Обычно в linux за это отвечает программа sendmail, а также от hostname. Если вы используете платный хостинг, то в личном кабинете можно настроить почтовые адреса и отправлять почту с них. Конечно вы можете в параметр from вставлять что угодно, но в заголовках письма все равно будет виден ваш hostname

Answer (score 2):

Пример -

```
<?php mail("joecool@example.com", "My Subject", "Line 1\nLine 2\nLine 3"); ?>
```

Дополнительные заголовки письма (additional headers) могут использоваться для указания кодировки письма, адреса отправителя, обратного адреса и множества других опций. Они должны быть разделены переводом строк: комбинацией "\r\n". Например, так:

```
<?php mail("nobody@example.com", "the subject", $message,"From: webmaster@ example.com \r\n" 
."X-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion()); ?>
```