# Почему при вводе mail почты, письмо через php не отправляется?

Tags: php, html, bootstrap

Здравствуйте!

Написал на PHP обратную связь и всё отлично работает, но вот одно НО, если вводить в поле email - "test@gmail.com", то всё работает, но если ввести "test@mail.ru", то письмо не отправляется вовсе.
Почта, куда приходит письмо, от Google.

```html
<form id="application" action="php/send.php" method="POST" name="application ">
<input name="name" id="name" maxlength="20" placeholder="Введите ваше имя" required />
<input name="email" type="email" id="email" maxlength="40" placeholder="Введите ваш E-mail" required/>
<input name="telephone" type="Tel" id="telephone" maxlength="20" placeholder="Введите ваш телефон" required />
<button class="FormButton" type="submit" form="application"><i class="fa fa-envelope" aria-hidden="true"></i> Получить прайс </button>
</form>

<?php 

$sendto   = "the.ivan.smirnov@gmail.com"; // почта, на которую приходит письмо
$username = $_POST['name'];   // данные из поля с Имя
$usertel = $_POST['telephone']; // данные из поля Телефон
$usermail = $_POST['email']; // данные из поля Email

// Формирование заголовка письма
$subject  = "Новое сообщение";
$headers  = "From: " . strip_tags($usermail) . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: ". strip_tags($usermail) . "\r\n";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8 \r\n";

// Формирование тела письма
$msg  = "<html><body style='font-family:Arial,sans-serif;'>";
$msg .= "<h2 style='font-weight:bold;border-bottom:1px dotted #ccc;'>Cообщение с сайта RECO</h2>\r\n";
$msg .= "<p><strong>От кого:</strong> ".$username."</p>\r\n";
$msg .= "<p><strong>Почта:</strong> ".$usermail."</p>\r\n";
$msg .= "<p><strong>Телефон:</strong> ".$usertel."</p>\r\n";
$msg .= "</body></html>";

// отправка сообщения
if(@mail($sendto, $subject, $msg, $headers)) {
  echo "<center><h1>Сообщение успешно отправленно</h1><br><h2>Мы свяжемся с вами в ближайшее время! </h2></center>";
} else {
  echo "<center><img src='img/ne-otprevleno.png'></center>";
}

?>
```

Comment: Не отправляется или не доходит? Похоже, что просто сработали фильтры Mail.Ru. Протестируйте на других сервисах - Яндексе, Рамблере и т.д. Если проблема только с Mail.Ru, то смотрите заголовки письма (возможно нет DKIM, SPF, DMARC и прочих атрибутов письма, повышающих вероятность его прохождения). Еще обратил внимание на то, что вы глушите ошибки функции mail. Что именно она выдает, если убрать подавление ошибок (@)?

Comment: Вы логи смотрели? Какие ошибки?

Comment: Никаких ошибок нет
http://th.890m.com/reco/%233/

Comment: Возможно так же ответ тут – https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/456690/Функция-mail-в-php/456748#456748

Comment: Этот вопрос задан/отвечен много раз. Автор просто поленился искать. За что плюсуют вопрос?

Comment: С локалхоста не все клиенты отправляют письма.

Answer (score 3):

**Отправка почты используя SMTP авторизацию**

```
 // пример использования
 require_once "SendMailSmtpClass.php"; // подключаем класс

 $mailSMTP = new SendMailSmtpClass('yourmail', 'password', 
 'ssl://smtp.yandex.ru', 'SenderName', 465); // создаем экземпляр класса
// $mailSMTP = new SendMailSmtpClass('логин', 'пароль', 'хост', 'имя 
отправителя');

// заголовок письма
$headers= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8\r\n"; // кодировка 
 письма
$headers .= "From: example <example@exaample.com>\r\n"; // от кого письмо !!! тут e-mail, через который происходит авторизация
$result =  $mailSMTP->send('to', 'header',
    '
             <h1>Hi ))</h1>

    ', $headers); // отправляем письмо
```

[Download SmtpMailer.php](https://mega.nz/#!PlMiXL4Q!wN1HgjxbIX8MlHY5A_whRSNOy1okh-AwDu5FyaSCOQ8)

Answer (score 2):

На данный момент (2017-й год) в общем случае вы с какого-то произвольного сервера как правило не сможете отправить письмо с произвольным обратным адресом. Вам нужно:

1. Настроить ящик, с которого будут приходить эти письма
2. Если этот ящик на популярных почтовых сервисах, то для отправки письма нужно использовать (E)SMTP с авторизацией
3. Адрес, который указал пользователь в форме, просто указывается в приходящем письме